# Correct way to structure Elixir GenServer with listening process

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, dialyzer

I'm using the [elixir-socket](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket) library as a way to connect to my backend application to an external websocket. I need this process to be managed (restart if something fails, backoff exponentially if it can't connect etc).

Currently, I've created a managing GenServer process that spawns a looping socket after a given amount of time (simplified below). I have a supervisor managing the `SocketManager` (and therefore the linked `Socket`) process:

**socket_manager.ex**

```
defmodule MyApp.SocketManager do
  def init(_) do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    state = %{socket: nil}
    {:ok, state, {:continue, :init}}
  end

  def handle_continue(:init, state) do
    Task.start_link(fn ->
      Socket.connect!()
    end)
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

**socket.ex**

```
defmodule MyApp.Socket do
  def connect! do
    socket = Socket.Web.connect!("xx.xx.com", secure: true, path: "/api/xxx")
    SocketManager.socket_connected(socket) # save the socket in the SocketManager state
    listen(socket)
  end

  defp listen(socket) do
    case socket |> Socket.Web.recv!() do
      {:text, data} ->
        # handle message
      {:close, :abnormal, _} ->
        Process.exit(self(), :kill)
      {:pong, _} ->
        nil
    end
    listen(socket)
  end
end
```

The above works great, however I'm not sure that this is the best way to structure this. From what I understand, `Task` should only be for tasks that have a defined lifespan, not for perpetual process. Also, when running `mix dialyzer` I get the following ouptut (referring to the `Task.spawn_link` line in `SocketManager`):

```
lib/myapp/socket_manager.ex:40:no_return
The created fun has no local return.
```

Can anyone help me with suggestions on how else to structure this and how I might be able to satisfy Dialyzer?

Thanks!

Comment: _Sidenote:_ to satisfy `dializer` one writes [`typespecs`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/typespecs.html#content) in the first place.

Comment: AFAICT, the proper way to go here would be a [`DynamicSupervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DynamicSupervisor.html#content).

Comment: Thanks! I'll give DynamicSupervisor a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is interested, this is what I ended up with. I think it's is a slightly better structure, although there are probably better/more idiomatic ways. It uses a DynamicSupervisor to supervise the socket process. It also no longer attempts to connect when the process

**socket_manager.ex**

```
defmodule MyApp.SocketManager do
  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def connect do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:connect})
  end

  def handle_cast({:connect}, state) do
    spec = %{
      id: LiveSocket,
      start: {MyApp.Socket, :connect, []},
      type: :worker
    }
    {:ok, pid} = DynamicSupervisor.start_child(MyApp.DynamicSupervisor, spec)
    Process.link(pid)
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```